# rake db:create wrong location

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, archlinux

I am currently setting up my first Rails environment.
When I try to run

```
rake db:create
```

the databases specified in *database.yml* are built, but not in the **db/** folder as they are supposed to, but instead in **/var/lib/mysql**. What must I do to make it build the databases in their proper locations? I am running Arch Linux.

Comment: Great answers, both of you! Would rep if I could:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only sqlite databases will be placed in the `db/` folder. Other database solutions like Mysql or Postgresql will create the database according to their own internal locations, often set during installation.

There is nothing wrong with where the database has been created and it shouldn't be moved or placed in the `db/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your database (mysql in this case it looks like) config determines where the actual data files are stored. It has nothing to do with rails.